# Pagination in PDO PHP

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

im trying to learn pagination with PHP/PDO.

```
            $limit = 20;
            $sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active != ''");
            $sth->execute(array(':county' => $county));

            $c = 1;
            while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
                echo 'Resutls will be here';
            $c++;
            }
```

Im unsure what to do next though, has anybody a good starting point I can reference from, or can explain the process for me?

Thanks

Comment: I do not see any problem with this question to be down voted . And whoever down voted it he should give us a reason

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not tested

```
$page  = 1;
$limit = 20;
$start = $page * $limit;

$conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, FALSE);
$sth = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM directory WHERE user_active LIMIT ?,?");
$sth->execute(array($start,$limit));
```

Comment: Thanks @Your Common Sense, how would I add next buttons however?

Comment: So no information about next button or actual page numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

Please use Below code for Pagination using PDO:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Simple Pagination Demo using PDO Query</title>
    <!-- CSS File -->
<link href="css/pagination.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<?php 
// mysql hostname
$hostname = 'localhost';
// mysql username
$username = 'root';
// mysql password
$password = '';
// Database Connection using PDO with try catch method. 
try { $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=PaginationTestDb", $username, $password); }
// In case of error PDO exception will show error message.
catch(PDOException $e) {    echo $e->getMessage();    }
// No. of adjacent pages shown on each side
$adjacents = 2;
// We will assign variable here for entry By. you can use your variables here.
$EntryBy = "furqan.aziz";
// We Will prepare SQL Query
$STM = $dbh->prepare("SELECT ServerName FROM statstracker WHERE EntryBy = :EntryBy");
// bind paramenters, Named paramenters alaways start with colon(:)
$STM->bindParam(':EntryBy', $EntryBy);
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
$STM->execute();
// Count no. of records 
$Records = $STM->rowCount();
// Your File Name will be the same like your php page name which is index.php
$targetpage = "index.php";
// Below is setting for no. of records per page.
$limit = 10; 
$page = $_GET['page'];
if($page) 
//First Item to dipaly on this page
    $start = ($page - 1) * $limit;          
else
//if no page variable is given, set start to 0
    $start = 0;                             
// Get data using PDO prepare Query.
$STM2 = $dbh->prepare("SELECT `SrNo`, `ServerName`, `HiMemUti`, `AvgMemUti`, `HiCpuUti`, `AvgCpuUti`, `HiIOPerSec`, `AvgIOPerSec`, `HiDiskUsage`, `AvgDsikUsage`, `EntryBy` FROM statstracker WHERE EntryBy = :EntryBy ORDER BY SrNo LIMIT $start, $limit");
// bind paramenters, Named paramenters alaways start with colon(:)
$STM2->bindParam(':EntryBy', $EntryBy);
// For Executing prepared statement we will use below function
$STM2->execute();
// We will fetch records like this and use foreach loop to show multiple Results later in bottom of the page.
 $STMrecords = $STM2->fetchAll();
// Setup page variables for display. If no page variable is given, default to 1.
if ($page == 0) $page = 1;
//previous page is page - 1                 
$prev = $page - 1;
//next page is page + 1                     
$next = $page + 1;
//lastpage is = total Records / items per page, rounded up.                         
$lastpage = ceil($Records/$limit);
//last page minus 1 
$lpm1 = $lastpage - 1;                      
//Now we apply our rules and draw the pagination object. We're actually saving the code to a variable in case we want to draw it more than once.
$pagination = "";
if($lastpage > 1)
{   
    $pagination .= "<div class='pagination'>";
    //previous button
    if ($page > 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$prev'>Previous</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Previous</span>"; 

    //pages 
    if ($lastpage < 7 + ($adjacents * 2))   //not enough pages to bother breaking it up
    {   
        for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
        {
            if ($counter == $page)
                $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
            else
                $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";                   
        }
    }
    elseif($lastpage > 5 + ($adjacents * 2))    //enough pages to hide some
    {
        //close to beginning; only hide later pages
        if($page < 1 + ($adjacents * 2))        
        {
            for ($counter = 1; $counter < 4 + ($adjacents * 2); $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //in middle; hide some front and some back
        elseif($lastpage - ($adjacents * 2) > $page && $page > ($adjacents * 2))
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $page - $adjacents; $counter <= $page + $adjacents; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";                   
            }
            $pagination.= "...";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lpm1'>$lpm1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$lastpage'>$lastpage</a>";     
        }
        //close to end; only hide early pages
        else
        {
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=1'>1</a>";
            $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=2'>2</a>";
            $pagination.= "...";
            for ($counter = $lastpage - (2 + ($adjacents * 2)); $counter <= $lastpage; $counter++)
            {
                if ($counter == $page)
                    $pagination.= "<span class='current'>$counter</span>";
                else
                    $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$counter'>$counter</a>";                   
            }
        }
    }

    //next button
    if ($page < $counter - 1) 
        $pagination.= "<a href='$targetpage?page=$next'>Next</a>";
    else
        $pagination.= "<span class='disabled'>Next</span>";
    $pagination.= "</div>\n";       
}
//Below is a start of table in which we will show records using foreach loop.
echo "<table class='mytableP'>";
// For Exporting Records to Excel we will send $EntryBy in link and will gate it on ExportToExcel page for stats for this user. 
echo"<tr><th th colspan=11>Simple Pagination Demo using PDO Queries</div></th></tr>";
echo"<a href='ExportToExcel.php?val=$EntryBy' target=_blank><img src='img/e2e.png' alt='Export To Excel' border='' class='e2e' /></a>";
echo"<tr><th>Sr#</th><th>Server</th><th>Hi Memory Utilization</th><th>Avg Memory Utilization</th><th>Hi CPU Utilization</th><th>Avg CPU Utilization</th><th>Hi I/O Utilization</th><th>Avg I/O Utilization</th><th>Hi Disk Usage</th><th>Avg Disk Usage</th><th>By</th></tr>";
// We use foreach loop here to echo records.
foreach($STMrecords as $r)
    {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[0] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[1] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[2] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[3] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[4] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[5] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[6] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[7] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[8] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[9] ."</td>";
        echo "<td>" .$r[10] ."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";  
    }
echo "</table>";
// For showing pagination below the table we will echo $pagination here after </table>. For showing above the table we will echo $pagination before <table>
echo $pagination;
// Closing MySQL database connection   
$dbh = null;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

For more details please visit below sites for source code and CSS styles

1. Click [here](http://crewow.com/Easy-Pagination-with-PDO-in-PHP-plus-Export-to-Excel.php)!
2. Click [here](http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Pagination-with-PHP-and-PDO.html)!

Comment: Nice pagination, in live search I use it, but what can I change to show the result without reload the page?

Comment: use session in live search so if the search query has some session value it will use that query