# Break PDO fetch results into different pages

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I seek help in resolving a problem where I have certain output in a page with PDO fetch and I would like to break the results on different pages with number of pages bellow. My PDO fetch looks like this:

```
<div class=list_results">
       <h1>Available Cities</h1>
       <?php 
            $select = new Users;
            $stmt = $select->selectcity();
            while( $row = $stmt->fetch()){ 
            echo "<div class='indextitle_list'><div class='listleft'><span class='folder_icon'><img src='../images/property.png'></span>".$row['cityname']."</div><div class='listright'><span class='smalllink'><a href='edit-city.php?id=".$row['id']."'>EDIT</a></span><span class='smalllink'><a href='delete-city.php?id=".$row['id']."'>DELETE</a></span></div></div>";
            } ?></div>
```

In which aproach you will suggest that I have to go to resolve this problem ?

Comment: Use the `LIMIT` option in the SQL query.

Comment: Search for `pagination pdo php` you will find a lot of tutorials on this. Here's a thread on it, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13901342/pagination-in-pdo-php.